# Installing TO a Flash drive

Tags: usb-drive, ubuntu-studio

I'm having a tough time getting a handle on this one.

Background - I'm deployed, and have one Laptop with me running Kubuntu
13.10.

I need to do some recording, and would like to use Ubuntu Studio.

I *was* running a Live CD, but then started thinking about installing to
a Flash drive, so, when I wanted to record, I just boot from the thumb
drive and use that.

There seems to be some confusion... When I find articles, many are 
centered around installing FROM a flash drive to a HD.

I came across a site - and a program called USB installer. It requires
you have an ISO and a Flash drive - and it does the rest.

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Did that, and when I booted from the drive, it came up with an 
installer.

I'd like to install TO the flash drive - but - won't that leave a bunch 
of install files ON the  flash drive I don't need?

Am I missing something?

Shouldn't I be running the install FROM the CD TO the Flash drive?

PS - I don't really care about saving anything to the flash drive - I'd 
just like it to be 'updateable' and save settings.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I believe this might be what you're looking for.
http://www.howtogeek.com/97177/how-to-put-ubuntu-linux-on-a-usb-thumb-drive-without-the-mess/

Comment: Not really. Doing it this way. I still am asked to 'try Ubuntu Studio' when I boot the thumb drive. My concern is, if I have the option to 'try' it, or 'install' it - aren't there a lot of installation files on the flash drive I don't need there anymore?

Comment: Hmm... if you're not concerned about saving stuff onto your Ubuntu USB then does it really matter if there are a few small installation files you don't need?  

I've used this before: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/
but it only runs on Windows and it allows you to create a persistent Ubuntu OS on a USB drive. You still do have the option to install Ubuntu onto the computer you're booting up with though.

Comment: Typically - no - but on an 8GB Flash drive - that 1.9G makes a difference.  I'm using the tool I mentioned earlier.  Couple of annoyances - like having to choose between running live or installing, and then it just logging in as UbuntuStudio... Other than that - working like a champ.